# Remove orphaned data without corresponding torrents in the rtorrent's list

Tags: bittorrent, cron, bash-scripting, rtorrent

I use `rtorrent` with a plenty of frontends like ruTorrent and Transdroid. Often, when I try to delete both the torrent and data through these frontends, the torrent is removed from the list but the data stays where is was. It happens periodically, not all the time.

I have a lot of space wasted by this unwanted data.

I wonder if there is a way to automatically (preferably by `cron`) to check the rtorrent download directory for such orphaned data and to remove it. It maybe a script or maybe rtorrent itself has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory.
Right-click the torrents and choose Save As...
Choose the new directory, tick Move data and Fast Resume
The data left behind is your orphaned data.

http://www.torrent-invites.com/showthread.php?t=230606